# Hierarchical data with different levels of depth - recursive function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a hierarchical table of vehicles. I want to write recursive function which find all descendants of given id. I want to do it without using path column. For example: find_children(2) sholud return array of ids [6,7,14,10,11,12,13,17,18,19,15,16]

[image]

I wrote function

```
public static function find_children ($id)
{
    is_array($id)?$ids=$id:$ids[]=$id;
    static $tab=[];
    $results=DB::table('vehicles')->whereIn('parent_id',$ids)->pluck('id');
    $how_many=DB::table('vehicles')->whereIn('parent_id',$ids)->count();
    if($how_many==0){
        return $tab;
    }

    $tab[]=$results;
    return  self::find_children($res);
}
```

For given example I receive  array of [6,7,14] in first iteration and array of [10,11] in the second one. I think the problem is different levels of depth in hierarchy. I don't know how to come back from level (a3,a4) up to (audi) and then (bmw)
Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with two function like below. let me know if you got any error.

```
public function getData($id)
{

    $vehicles =DB::table('vehicles')->get();

    return  $this->find_children($vehicles,$id);
}

public function find_children($vehicles,$id)
{
    $ids = [];
    foreach($vehicles as $v)
    {
        if($id == $v->parent_id)
        {
            $ids[] = $v->id;

            $childids = $this->find_children($vehicles,$v->parent_id);

            $ids = array_merge($ids,$childids);
        }
    }
    $response = array_unique($ids);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: There are not any errors, but empty screen is displayed.

Comment: can you check insight foreach loop `dd($id,$v->parent_id);` if you get values then check insight if condition and try